# Como paginar muchos datos con jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, nodejs, datatables

estoy haciendo una web y en una de mis consultas sql me he encontrado con 10000 registros, por lo que datatables se toma hasta casi 5 minutos para paginar todos los datos, existe alguna configuración para hacer que esto vaya mas rápido?? es prácticamente inusable la web ya que tarda muchísimo, los datos los cargo desde una llamada ajax tal que así:

```
 <tbody class="bodyFincas">

 </tbody>
```

y mi archivo js es este:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/fincas",
        data: "",
        success: function (fincas) {
            console.log(fincas); 
            let filas = "";

            for(let i = 0; i<fincas.length; i++){
              
                let defecto = "";
                let exenta = "";
                let baja = "";

                if(fincas[i].defecto == 0){
                    defecto += `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input defecto" id="Check1">`;
                }else{
                    defecto += `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input defecto" checked
                    id="Check1">`;
                }              
                
                if(fincas[i].exenta == 0){
                    exenta += `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input exenta" id="Check2">`;
                }else{
                    exenta += `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input exenta" checked
                    id="Check2">`;
                }       

                if(fincas[i].baja == 0){
                    baja += `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input baja" id="Check3">`;
                }else{
                    baja += `<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input baja" checked
                    id="Check3">`;
                }       


                filas += `
                    <tr>
                        <td data-column="Nº:">
                            ${fincas[i].numeroFinca}
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Código:">
                            ${fincas[i].codigoSocio}
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Nombre:">{
                            ${fincas[i].nombreSocio}
                        </td>
                       
                        <td data-column="Fecha alta:">
                            ${fincas[i].fechaAlta}
                        </td>
                       
                        <td data-column="Porcentaje:">
                            ${fincas[i].porcentaje}%
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Superficie imputada:">
                            ${fincas[i].superficieImputada}
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Defecto:" class="td-check">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                ${defecto}                                   
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="Check1"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Código regante:">
                            ${fincas[i].codigoRegante}
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Nombre regante:">
                            ${fincas[i].nombreRegante}
                        </td>

                        <td data-column="Exenta:" class="td-check">
                            <div class="form-check">
                                ${exenta}
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="Check2"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>


                        <td data-column="Baja:" class="td-check">
                            <div class="form-check"> 
                                ${baja}
                                <label class="form-check-label" for="Check3"></label>
                            </div>
                        </td>


                        <td data-column="Polígono:">
                            ${fincas[i].poligono}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Parcela:">
                            ${fincas[i].parcela}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Paraje:">
                            ${fincas[i].paraje}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Zona rie
                            go:">${fincas[i].zonaRiego}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Subparcela:">
                            ${fincas[i].subParcela}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Municipio:">
                            ${fincas[i].municipio}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Población:">
                            ${fincas[i].poblacion}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Adjunto municip
                            io:">${fincas[i].adjuntoMunicipio}
                        </td>  
                        <td data-column="Tarifa:">
                            ${fincas[i].tarifa}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="DNI:">
                            ${fincas[i].dni}
                        </td>
                        <td data-column="Demarcación:">
                            ${fincas[i].demarcacion}
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                `;  
            }

            console.log(filas);

            $('.bodyFincas').append(filas);

        }
    });
});
```

Esta es mi llamada a la ruta desde el servidor:

```
app.post('/fincas', login, (req, res) => {
    let token = req.session.usuario.token

    let fincasDB = async() => {
        await sql.connect(config);
        let db = new sql.Request();
        db.input("token", sql.VarChar('100'), token);
        let result = await db.execute('LISTADO_CONSULTA_FINCAS');
        return result.recordset;
    }

    fincasDB().then(fincas => {
        console.log(fincas);
        return res.status(200).json(fincas);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('error al sacar las fincas', err);
        return res.status(404).redirect('/404');
    });
});
```

¿Alguien sabe como puedo solucionar esto y hacer que no tarde en ir generando los datos? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Deberías de limitar la query de tu API de manera que te saque los datos en un rango, por ejemplo de 10 en 10, puedes hacerlo con LIMIT

Comment: Claro pero no existe una opción dentro del datatable?? ya que no se muy bién como podría ir generando los datos a medida que voy paginando en la web

Comment: Datatables te permite hacer uso del server-side processing.
Aquí está toda la info:
[Datatables server-side](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html)